# Oracle Text Search - fuzzy results not having exact length

Tags: sql, oracle, search

i am currently using fuzzy search like my search criteria is 'mine' here.

```
select * from media_detail where contains(description,'fuzzy(mine)')>0;
```

it returns me

```
mine
mini
mani
```

where as i want these to be included in result like

```
mine
mini
mani
mining
minded
minimum
miner
min
nine
```

Answer (score 0):

see if this is ok:

```
table ns_words
    mine
    mini
    mani
    nikhil
    sugandh
    mining
    mining

CREATE INDEX myindex2 ON ns_words(a) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT;
select * from ns_words where contains(a,'fuzzy(mine)')>0 or 
contains(a,'fuzzy(mining)')>0;
output:   
mine
mini
mining
```

Comment: noun and pronoun here is just an example here to understand, actually i need all those results in return which may be of exact length (like in case of fuzzy) or may vary in length with fuzziness.